# d3.js create same svg object with different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a script, that works fine and create a chord diagram I need. 
But now I want to create the same `.svg` file on another `div` but with different matrix. 
Should I duplicate the same script for a new svg, or I can do in more efficient way?

You can find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kepkjgd0/).

Now my `.Js` script use `drawChordWithMatrix(matrix_T1_T2)` to show chord on div with `id chart`
What should I do to run `drawChordWithMatrix(matrix_T2_T3)` on `id chart1`

Comment: Hmm, it is tough with the code you have as is. Really you need to encapsulate the "setup", "drawing" and "appending" sections into functions 
 - so that they can be called to work with a specific svg instance (rather than a single hard coded one)...maybe take a look at: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/ to get a good overview of reusable components in d3.

Comment: @Fraser thanks for response. Well, I see your point. Actually incapsulating the logic is not a big deal. I can't understand how can I link `div` and `svg`. I don't think, that creating a div with another id and creating a new svg for this id is good approach. I think that my script should execute two function `drawChordWithMatrix(matrix_T1_T2)`, `drawChordWithMatrix(matrix_T2_T3)`.

Comment: well the accepted answer does exactly that - and it is the approach - you pass parameters to a reusable function that encapsulates the code you need to repeat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way i can think is

1) Move the SVG creation into the `drawChordWithMatrix`

So you need to pass the id to which you need to attach the SVG.
something like this `function drawChordWithMatrix(matrix, id)`, and you create your SVG in the function like this.

```
var svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")//selecting on basis of ID.
            .attr("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right))
            .attr("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom));
```

2) Next move all functions like fade, fadeOnChord , etc.. into the `drawChordWithMatrix` so that they all have the same scope.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9r37mqgr/)